# Why clipboard that was filled for my app is no longer accessible in the same app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've written this function for fill the *Android* `clipboard`:

```
fun copyToClip(s: String = "") {
  val clipboard = cx.getSystemService
     (Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
  val clip = ClipData.newPlainText(if (s == "") "" else "Formula", s);
  clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

And this function for paste the `clipboard` content

```
fun clipToPaste(): String {
  val clipboard = cx.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) 
        as ClipboardManager
  if ((!clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) || 
     !(clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)))
    return ""
  else
    return clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString()
}
```

And this routine for testing empty `clipboard`.

```
fun hasClip(): Boolean {
  val clipboard = cx.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) 
    as ClipboardManager
  if ((clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) ||
  clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))
    return clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString().length!=0
  return false
}
```

And it works. However, some time after `hasClip` returns `false`, when I've debugged, the clipboard value is `""` (empty).

The weird thing is that `clipboard` content is still available for other system apps, but no longer for my own app.

I have no idea what is happening...

**PS**: How my app is for running in cell phone before API 28, I don't use `clearPrimaryClip` function for clearing the `clipboard`

**UPDATE**

With new tests using the editor *MonoSpace*, that shows all active text clipboards, I've concluded that this piece of code is buggy

```
   val clipboard = cx.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) 
    as ClipboardManager
  val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", "")
  clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
```

The failure is because this method doesn't clear any entries of Clipboard and neither create a new empty one. If you have 4 entries, the same 4 entries go on. The only difference is that you cannot access the clipboard inside app until you copy something inside the app.

Assuming the app must be compatible with pre API 28, there is no known way to erase the Clipboard without low-level programming.

Comment: Add some logging to `hasClip()`, so you can find out what the values are of `clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()`, `clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)`, and `clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString().length` for your calls. Then, see what those values are when `hasClip()` starts returning `false`.

Comment: I've already done it. `clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()` is `true`, `clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)` is also `true`. and `clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString().length` is `0`. Therefore `hasClip` return `false`, however the clipboard content exists for other apps and it's not empty.